# SwipeJS start callback

Tags: javascript, swipe

I'm using SwipeJS (http://swipejs.com/) plugin in a application but I need a callback to know when the animation start. How to do this?

Comment: When I Google `SwipeJS start callback`, I see a patch on Github

Comment: I´ve already tested this "lib" but the event only happens when I leave the mouse. What I want is an event called when mouse just move. Thanks!